# Suspending environments and resuming by another environment

Tags: macros, environments

Is it possible to **interrupt** a LaTeX environment, say `OuterEnv`, by another environment, say `InnerEnv`, the later closing the first in the environment startup code, doing 'whatever' and then **resuming** the outer one in the end code, proceeding as if *nothing* has been done before?

This is not a question about resuming `enumerate` etc. lists.

I know there might be issues with environment arguments and especially with the environment *startup code*, let alone the `grouping` feature of environments.

I fear the answer is `no` :-(

Here is a non-working MWE. LaTeX complains about the `InnerEnv` ending the `OuterEnv` (of course ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{OuterEnv}{%
\parindent0pt
  Foo

  \textcolor{red}{\blindtext}%
}{%

Bar\vskip2\baselineskip% Just for debugging
}

\newenvironment{InnerEnv}{%
\end{OuterEnv} % Fails
Closing Outer...

\textcolor{blue}{\blindtext}%
}{%

Resuming Outer\vskip3\baselineskip 
\begin{OuterEnv} %Fails too
}


\begin{document}

\begin{OuterEnv}

\begin{InnerEnv}
\end{InnerEnv}
\end{OuterEnv}

\end{document}
```

I dot not stick on `\newenvironment`. `\NewDocumentEnvironment` for `xparse` will do too, of course!

Comment: Interesting idea! Basically this means that you want to temporarily escape the current group (or inject stuff in the outer group), a bit like `\global`, but just "one level up". I don't think this is possible, but I am looking forward to the answers of egreg, David, Bruno et al.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I am aware about the grouping stuff. Perhaps something with `\aftergroup`? I think our Gurus will have answers (either good or bad ;-))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this at home...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{OuterEnv}{%
\parindent0pt
  Foo

  \textcolor{red}{\blindtext}%
}{%

Bar\vskip2\baselineskip% Just for debugging
}

\newenvironment{InnerEnv}{%
\endgroup
\end{OuterEnv} % Fails
Closing Outer...

\textcolor{blue}{\blindtext}%
}{%

Resuming Outer\vskip3\baselineskip 
\begin{OuterEnv} %Fails too
\begingroup
\def\@currenvir{InnerEnv}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{OuterEnv}

\begin{InnerEnv}
\end{InnerEnv}
\end{OuterEnv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the `\@currenvir` stuff. `\endgroup` and `\begingroup` was there in previous version, but it was not enough, obviously. What are the caveats?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer caveats? a list as long as your arm:-) It makes all kinds of assumptions about both environments. Any environment using special formatting is likely to fail (tabular and friends) any environment using catcode tricks will fail (verbatim, listings, ...) any environment that traps the environment body as a macro will fail (ams alignments, tabularx, anything defined by the environ package commands) any environment that assumes its begin and end code are in the same group will fail, some other things not listed will fail. Apart from that, it should always work.

Comment: Ok, three or four environments remaining then ;-)