# Terminate environments within environment in class function

Tags: environments, documentclass-writing

I'm writing a class for a document, that inherits from `article`, and I encountered a problem with this: the document should be all in two columns, except the abstract. For the two columns, I use the `multicol` package.

The asbtract would also display in two columns, and my first attempt was to redefine the abstract environment in the .cls file to the next:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\end{multicols}\begin{center}{\scshape Resúmen}\end{center} }
{\begin{multicols}{2}}
```

together with:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}
```

I thought that would "pause" the multicols environment, allowing the abstract to be in one column.

The first problem is that I get the errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{abstract} on input line 9 ended by \end{multicols}.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{multicols} on input line 11 ended by \end{abstract}.
```

So it's not putting the `\end{multicols}` where I thought it would, but before the `\end{abstract}`, and so on.

The second problem, is that if a remove everything, the title from `\maketitle` also appears within a column.

How could I make that? Like pause the multicols environment from within a defined environment? If that can't be done I would appreciate any other more elegant solution.

I would like to make it as independent as possible from the `.tex` file. That is, I could just write the `multicol` environment in the text in the `tex` file, but I would like the `.cls` file to deal with this.

Thank you

Comment: Somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237478/suspending-environments-and-resuming-by-another-environment

Comment: The problem is, that each environment keeps track which environment is active, in the `\@currenvir` macro (or 'variable') -- and you should `store` the old abstract definition

Comment: There is also the command `\abstractname` to use instead of *Resúmen*.

Comment: Do you want the whole abstract full textwidth or only the word ‘abstract’?

Comment: @Bernard The whole abstract

Comment: @Sigur I know, but since I was redefining it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do this at home ;-)**

The trick is to `fake` the current environment to be `multicols` right at the start of `abstract`, then stopping the multicols environment, setting the abstract environment correctly and using `\AfterEndDocument` from `etoolbox` package to resume the `\begin{multicols}{2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\latexabstractend\endabstract

\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\def\@currenvir{multicols}\end{multicols}\def\@currenvir{abstract}\begin{center}{\scshape \abstractname}\end{center} }
{\latexabstractend}%

\AfterEndEnvironment{abstract}{\begin{multicols}{2}}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sigur: Wouldn't it be more useful to make that comment at the OP? ;-)

Comment: @Sigur: Thanks anyway, I used your suggestion!

Comment: It would be better to store the usual `abstract` stuff. This can still be done, but for the moment, I omitted this

Comment: Thank you. I can see that faking the current environment could be a bit dangerous... I will use this, I think. I didn't know though of the package etoolbox. I saw that it also has an `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` function, so I tried to make the same interruption I was trying to make, but using those function (`BeforeBegin` and `AfterEnd`), and it worked. It only messed up the title (it still tries to put it in two columns), but it looks like it advances. I will try to fix the title, and if I can't I will use your solution. The "don't do this at home" scares me a bit xD. Thank you again

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Yes, `BeforeBeginEnvironment` would be an alternative, of course

Comment: I just copied the `maketitle` definition adding the `\end{multicols}` at the begining, and `\begin{multicols}{2}` at the end and it works very smoothly. The only problem I see with this is that the structure of the document will be:

`\begin{multicols}{2}\end{multicols}
%TITLE HERE%
\begin{multicols}{2}\end{multicols}
%ABSTRACT%\begin{multicols}{2}
%REST OF DOCUMENT%...`

I find it a bit dirty, although I don't see it introduces any vertical unncecesary spacing or anything in each empty multicols environment... Is there some deep problem with that?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Well, that's again another question. You should perhaps not start just copying other code from other classes in your class document. Try to make an ordinary document and then transform that to a class file. You've not shown a single file yet, what is really in your document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider using the `twocolumn` option of the documentclass, you can use either the `@twocolumnfalse` environment, or the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

**@twocolumnfalse environment:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, spanish]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A nice title}
\author{Ye author}
\date{\today}
\setlength\columnsep{3em}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[%
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      This is a test for an abstract in a two column environment. This is a test for an abstract in a two column environment. This is a test for an abstract in a two column environment. This is a test for an abstract in a two column environment.
    \end{abstract}
    \vskip2\baselineskip
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
```

]%
 {%

```
  \lipsum[1-6]
```

}%

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

**strip environment:**
    \documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn, twoside, spanish]{article}%
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{fourier, cuted, erewhon}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \title{A nice title}
    \author{Ye author}
    \date{\today}
    \setlength\columnsep{3em}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\stripsep\relax}
  \centering
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
      This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode.
    \end{minipage}
  \end{abstract}
  \vskip2\baselineskip
\end{strip}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]